# How to add \ in a string before a special character

Tags: regex, sed

I have a string: 816788[20].

I want to add \ before [ and ] characters.

So the correct result shoud be:

```
816788\[20\]
```

The script code is:

```
str="816788[20]"
newStr=`echo $str | sed  's/\[/\\\[/' `
echo $newStr
```

But unlucky, It is fail. I have tried:

```
  newStr=`echo $str | sed  's/\[/\"\"\[/' `
```

and

```
 newStr=`echo $str | sed  's/\[/\"\["/' `
```

there are all wrong, Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's/[][]/\\&/g'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/ddYMBB):

```
str="816788[20]"
newStr=$(sed 's/[][]/\\&/g' <<< "$str")
echo $newStr
# => 816788\[20\]
```

**Details**

- `[][]` matches either `[` or `]`
- `\\` - in the replacement part, inserts `\` (if you use a single `\`, it will escape `&` placeholder and it will be treated as a literal `&` char)
- `&` - the placeholder for the whole match
- `g`  - replaces all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
sed 's|\[|\\[|;s|\]|\\]|'
```

example

```
echo "816788[20]" | sed 's|\[|\\[|;s|\]|\\]|'
```

output

```
816788\[20\]
```